# Right Align Button Inside Div Tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a label left aligned and a button right aligned all within a div tag?  My label aligns perfectly, my button is not even close (may even be appearing outside of the div tag.  Can someone assist?

```
<div id="PlaceHolder" runat="server" visible="false">
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDisplay" CssClass="BoldTextBlack"> </asp:Label>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRollBack" CssClass="Buttons" style="float:right"
    Text="Roll Back Last Change" OnClick="btnRollBack_Click" Height="30px" Width="119px" /> 
</div>
```

After additional testing it seems that adding in the `style="float:right"` is what skews the alignment

Comment: can you provide more context

Comment: @godmode - I want the label and the button to appear on the same "line" on the web form.  Have the label on the left side and the button on the right side.  How it currently appears the button is not aligned with the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning to put the label and button where you want them.  You want them positioned relative to your #Placeholder div, so you need to add to the CSS there as well.

Adding `position: relative;` to PlaceHolder shouldn't change how that div looks, but it tells the browser to position any enclosed, absolutely-positioned elements in relation to THIS div, instead of another one/the page as a whole:

```
#PlaceHolder {
   position: relative;  
}
```

Then we can use absolute positioning to get the label and button exactly where we want.  I don't have your design specs, so I'm making things up for the actual measurements :)

We'll tell the label to position its left edge exactly 10px from the left edge of #PlaceHolder, and its bottom edge 10px up from the bottom edge of #PlaceHolder.

```
#lblDisplay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Now we'll tell the button to position its right edge exactly 10px from the right edge of #PlaceHolder, and its bottom edge 10px up from the bottom edge of #PlaceHolder.

```
#btnRollBack {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```